# Different spiritual / cultural forms of love and the right form of love to use in translating "in love, we trust"

Tags: roman-culture, catechism-catholic-church

In trying to translate "in love we trust," (love, in this case, not referring to the romantic-passionate form of love, definitely not eros, but rather universal spiritual love vibration) in the likes of "in domino confido" or "in domino semper," Google translate came up with "in caritate speramus."

It seems caritate refers to charity-love. Not exactly sure if charity-love means something different to the Romans or in the Latin language. Not specifically referring to any of the ancient Greek's many different famous forms of love... This makes me wonder about w*hich form of love to use in the case of general non-romantic non-specific-to-any-religion's form of love, viz., love as a universal vibration*?

How do you translate, "in [spiritual universal vibration] love, we trust", to convey the same idea of the concept of love in context?